# Select box data array

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
$data = array(5 => "Rating 5", 6 => "Rating 6");
```

I am trying to get a row of values from MySQL and store it in the above array format. I cannot seem to be getting it right.

I have tried something like below;

```
foreach($dbvalues as $value)
{
  $data[] = array($value->id => $value->ratings);
}
```

But cannot seem to get it working. The reason I want to get the array in the above format is because I want to dynamically populate the select box as shown below;

```
$form->input_select('rating','Rating','','ratingID', '','','',$data);
```

Comment: Why not use `$data[$value->id] = $value->ratings` if you don't want to use a nested array?

Comment: @NicoHaase, wow you are a genius. Thank you so much.